# How to select label tags that do not have a span inside them using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible, using CSS, to target all label tags that do not have a span in them:

```
<label><span></span>foo</label>    <-- don't target this one
<label>bar</label>                 <-- do target this one
```

Comment: 1. What are you trying to achieve after selecting that `label`? 2. Can you modify the HTML?

Comment: No I can't modify the html.  I want to add the span in to these targeted label tags.

Comment: Hmm. To add a new element to another element you'd use JavaScript, not CSS. With JavaScript you can pull all `label` elements and iterate through removing the ones with `span` children.

Comment: I was thinking that I might have to use jQuery, so my targeting question would help here too.

Comment: Do you want to target `label` elements with no content whatsoever, as your example shows, or just ones with no `span` tags inside them?

Comment: Ones with no span - I have edited my question to show some content now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was thinking that I might have to use jQuery, so my targeting question would help here too.

With jQuery you can iterate through each `label`, filtering out any which contain a `span` element. For this we can use [jQuery's `filter()` method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

> The second form of this method [`filter`] allows us to filter elements against a function rather than a selector. For each element, if the function returns `true` (or a "truthy" value), the element will be included in the filtered set; otherwise, it will be excluded.

```
$('label').filter(function() {
    return $(this).children('span').length == 0;
});
```

This selects all `label` elements (`$('label')`), then iterates through them all using `filter()` to ensure no children `span` elements are found (if there were child `span` elements, the `length` property would be equal to the number of matches).

Comment: I was hoping for a css solution, but this works - thank you

Answer (score 2):

you could try using the `:empty` pseudo selector.

```
label:empty{//some css here}
```

If you want to target them so you could modify the content, you should use JavaScript, like this jQuery code:

```
$('label:empty').html('Your added html content here');
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do once you've targeted them.

If you want to target text outside the span, then you can do something like

```
label { color: red; }
label span { all: initial; }
```

But I have no idea if this will solve your problem, or even what your problem is.